# Как программно добавить товар в opencart?

Tags: api, opencart

Есть Opencart 2.1
Есть модуль поиска специализировнного товара - запчасти автомобилей в связке с tecdoc.
Когда заказ отправляется клиентом на платформу все ОК - и он для просмотра доступен. Если заказ редактировать - система пишет нет такого товара(
Умом дошел до того, что это делать надо через API.
Где можно посмотреть - как синхронизировать номенклатуру и остатки модуля и opencart через API????

Comment: "заказ отправляется клиентом на платформу"? поясните. И редактируете заказ из вы из админки или клиент из личного кабинета? В какой момент выбрасывает сообщение, на каком действии?

Comment: При нажатии клиентом заказать - заказ уходит в систему.

Comment: А вот с админки, заказ можно посмотреть, но если этот товар еще не заказывался у нас, то товар еще не существует.

Comment: А если заказывался, то уже должен существовать. На умных форумах просто пишут api, а как реализовать - не понятно....